# Error while creating istio ingress gateway in istio 1.2.5

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

I'm creating aks-engine on azure vmss, I tried deploying istio 1.0.1 and 1.2.5, in 1.0.1 I was able to create an internal load balancer as istio ingress gateway. But in 1.2.5 I'm getting an error "service-controller  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: user-supplied IP Address true was not found in resource group" though I've specified the resource group name in the annotations --set controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group=""

Comment: Can you specify the exact command that fails?

Comment: the ingress deployment is pending with the external IP, and giving the error "service-controller Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: user-supplied IP Address true was not found in resource group" though I've specified the resource group name in the annotations --set controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group="

Comment: I mean the exact YAML.

Comment: helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio \
  --name istio \
  --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.loadBalancerIP=${LOAD_BALANCER_IP} \
  --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.serviceAnnotations.'service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal="true"' \
  --set tracing.enabled=true \
  --set grafana.enabled=true \
  --set servicegraph.enabled=true \
  --set kiali.enabled=true \
  --set pilot.traceSampling=$TRACING_AMOUNT \
  --set global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode=ALLOW_ANY  \
  --namespace istio-system > istio.yaml

Comment: Can you check that ${LOAD_BALANCER_IP} contains a valid IP address?

Comment: yes, it is a valid IP